# Heroku Issues with re-directs from non-www to www

Tags: redirect, heroku, http-status-code-301, forward, no-www

I have set up my application with SSL at e.g. www.mydomainhere.com

Through my DNS provider, I have set up a URL forward to go from mydomainhere.com to www.mydomainhere.com and that works.  However, if I try to go to mydomainhere.com/users or any other variation it throws me to a "Nothing exists here but here is a bunch of ads page", but if I type in www.mydomainhere.com/users then it works perfectly.

I am using Heroku with SSL endpoint and mydomain.com for DNS provider.  Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Heroku issue, but rather an issue with your DNS redirection. Clearly they are not redirecting properly. If you can't get your DNS provider to redirect properly, I recommend changing DNS providers.